# How to round a float to one digit after the dot

Tags: c#, .net-core

Most probably, it's a duplicate, and I don't understand some basics, and thus deserve a downvote, but it just drives me crazy.

I'm using **C#** and **.NET Core** on Mac OS.

I have a float `9.74999` and I want to round it to one digit after the dot and get `9.8` (*like it should work according to what I remember from primary school: 9.749 -> 9.75 -> 9.8 -> 10*).

I tried this:

```
float rounded = (float)Math.Round(9.74999f, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
// rounded = 9.7
```

Why it's not `9.8`? So, it just takes the digit of interest (`7`) and the following one (`4`) and doesn't care about the rest (`999`)?

And this construction actually gives me what I want:

```
float rounded = (float)Math.Round(
    (float)Math.Round(9.74999f, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
    1,
    MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero
);
// rounded = 9.8
```

So, the only way I can get `9.8` out of `9.74999` is by performing two `Round` operations:

1. First `Round` with `2` decimals;
2. Second `Round` with the result of the first one and `1` decimal.

Is this a proper way to do it?

---

### Update

I see now that at school we were given a concept of double (triple, etc) rounding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding), which accumulates error on each step, and that's not the rounding that is used by `Math.Round`, so that's why I am not getting what I expect to get (`9.749` -> `9.75` -> `9.8`).

But I do need to perform exactly such a "consequential" rounding, going from right to left, digit by digit. So, I guess, there is no standard function for that, and I need to implement it myself.

Comment: Why should it go to 9.8?  9.7 is *closer*. I think you are misremembering your primary school.  9.7 is 0.04999 away, and 9.8 is 0.05001 away, and the latter is *bigger*. Can you explain why you would like to *round off* to the number that has *a bigger rounding error*?

Comment: `9.75` goes to `9.7`

Comment: Is there a way one could retake primary school?

Comment: @Tigran `Math.Round(9.75, 1)` will result in `9.8`

Comment: You may want to remove *"proper mathematical rounding"* from the title of this question...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because problem is a simple misunderstanding by OP of how rounding works.

Comment: Note that floats are not decimal values; they are fractions with a power of two, not ten, in the denominator. Expect that sometimes when you are doing the math, you're going to get 7.399999 when you expect 7.4; this could affect your algorithm. If you need exact representation of decimals, **use the decimal type**.

Answer (score 4):

In Math, 9.74999 rounds to 9.7. The code is using math.

Edit with less snark: 9.75 and greater will around to 9.8. Anything less than 9.75 (and greater than or equal to 9.65) will round to 9.7. I think you're confusing yourself and thinking that the 999 will round the .74 to a .75, but that's not the case.

Comment: Assining "In Math" is referring to the static C# `Math` class, this is slightly inaccurate.  `Math.Round(9.65,1)` will round to 9.6.  This is because C# defaults to [`MidpointRounding.ToEven`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx), not `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`.